# How to merge multiple columns of values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
data = {'Wavelength Band1': [410, 411, 412], 'Band1': [0, 0, 0],
        'Wavelength Band2': [500, 501, 502], 'Band2': [0, 0.0007, 0.0021],
        'Wavelength Band3': [730, 745, 750], 'Band3': [0.0023, 0.0046, 0.007]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

I want to join all columns of *Wavelength BandX* into a single column *Wavelength*. If *BandX* has no corresponding value in a specific Wavelength then it should be *NaN*.

Desired output:

```
output = {'Wavelength': [410, 411, 412, 500, 501, 502, 730, 745, 750],
          'Band1': [0, 0, 0, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN],
          'Band2': [NaN, NaN, NaN, 0, 0.0007, 0.0021, NaN, NaN, NaN],
          'Band3': [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.0023, 0.0046, 0.007]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=output)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is a bit tricky, but here's one with `wide_to_long`

```
u = pd.wide_to_long(
      df.reset_index(), stubnames=['Wavelength'], i='index', j='id', sep=' ', suffix='Band\d+')

d = u.filter(like='Band')

i = u.index.get_level_values('id').to_numpy()
j = d.columns.to_numpy()

m = i[:, None] != j

d.mask(m).assign(Wavelength=u['Wavelength']).reset_index(1, drop=True)
```

```
       Band1   Band2   Band3  Wavelength
index
0        0.0     NaN     NaN         410
1        0.0     NaN     NaN         411
2        0.0     NaN     NaN         412
0        NaN  0.0000     NaN         500
1        NaN  0.0007     NaN         501
2        NaN  0.0021     NaN         502
0        NaN     NaN  0.0023         730
1        NaN     NaN  0.0046         745
2        NaN     NaN  0.0070         750
```

---

***Explanation***

The first step gets us 90% of the way there:

```
>>> u
             Band1   Band2   Band3  Wavelength
index id
0     Band1      0  0.0000  0.0023         410
1     Band1      0  0.0007  0.0046         411
2     Band1      0  0.0021  0.0070         412
0     Band2      0  0.0000  0.0023         500
1     Band2      0  0.0007  0.0046         501
2     Band2      0  0.0021  0.0070         502
0     Band3      0  0.0000  0.0023         730
1     Band3      0  0.0007  0.0046         745
2     Band3      0  0.0021  0.0070         750
```

We just need to mask on the wavelengths that don't match up with the `id` level values from the `wide_to_long` operation, which we can do using broadcasted comparison from `numpy`:

```
>>> m
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False]])
```

The falsey values in the mask are the values where the column matches the index, and we want to keep those.